# mootools and iframem, show div at top right corner

Tags: javascript, html, css, mootools

I have iframe popup for image, and close button within that iframe. I want that close button at top corner of iframe with some portion outside of iframe. How can I apply it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create CSS Class for that and apply it on `input button` as bellow.

```
<input type="image" id="DemoID" class="closeBut" src="../App_Themes/NewTheme/facebox/GrayClose.png" style="border-width:0px;">
```

> CSS Class as bellow

```
.closeBut{
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #777;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: -8px;
    right: -8px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-indent: -9999em;
    background: url(../App_Themes/NewTheme/facebox/GrayClose.png) no-repeat;
    outline: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```